# Show and hide multiple dynamic divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to show and hide a div when I click on it and that's ok but I have problem to found a solution to close the others if previously the user open one of the others.
[image: The image show an example]

The second image show what's append when I click on another div:

[image: Second click]

And also if I would like to close I have to click on each opened div's...

That's my javascript code:

```
       function toggle_visibility(id) {
           var e = document.getElementById(id);
           var el = document.getElementById('matdidcor');
           if(e.style.display == 'block') {
              e.style.display = 'none';
              el.style.height = 0 + 'px';
          } else {
              e.style.display = 'block';
              el.style.height = 420 + 'px';
          }
       }
```

And this is the HTML

```
    <section id="slidefeature" class="greenBack">
      <div class="container-fluid"> 
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-4" id="slidefeatures"> 
            <!--======= FEATURE =========-->
            <ul class="row">
              <!--======= SERVICES 1 =========-->
                <a onclick="toggle_visibility('DIDATICA');" class="DIDATICA">          
             <li>
                <div class="text-center" style="color: #FFF !important;">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-3x"></i> 
                </div>             
                <div class="top text-center pad20">
                  <h5>DIDATICA</h5>
                  <hr>
                  </div>
              </li>
              </a>
                </ul>
            </div>        

          <div class="col-md-4" id="slidefeatures"> 
            <!--======= FEATURE =========-->
            <ul class="row">
              <!--======= SERVICES 1 =========-->
                <a onclick="toggle_visibility('MATERIAL');" class="MATERIAL">          
             <li>
                <div class="text-center" style="color: #FFF !important;">
                    <i class="fa fa-book fa-3x"></i> 
                </div>             
                <div class="top text-center pad20">
                  <h5>MATERIAL</h5>
                  <hr>
                  </div>
              </li>
              </a>
                </ul>
            </div>        

          <div class="col-md-4" id="slidefeatures"> 
            <!--======= FEATURE =========-->
            <ul class="row">
              <!--======= SERVICES 1 =========-->
                <a onclick="toggle_visibility('CURSOS');" class="CURSOS">          
             <li>
                <div class="text-center" style="color: #FFF !important;">
                    <i class="fa fa-copy fa-3x"></i> 
                </div>             
                <div class="top text-center pad20">
                  <h5>CURSOS</h5>
                  <hr>
                  </div>
              </li>
              </a>
                </ul>
            </div>        
                    </div>
      </div>     
    </section>

    <div id="matdidcor" style="height: 420px;">
<div class="pad20">
  <ul>
            <li class="col-sm-12 pad20" style="display: block;" id="DIDATICA"> 
        <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="wp-content/uploads/2015/03/news-img.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="text-left">
                  <h3>DIDATICA</h3>
                          <p>sample text</p>
                  <div class="row"> 
                        </div>
      </div>
    </div></li>
                <li class="col-sm-12 pad20" style="display:none" id="MATERIAL"> 
        <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="wp-content/uploads/2015/03/news-img.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="text-left">
                  <h3>MATERIAL</h3>
                          <p>sample text</p>
                  <div class="row"> 
                        </div>
      </div>
    </div></li>
                <li class="col-sm-12 pad20" style="display:none" id="CURSOS"> 
        <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="wp-content/uploads/2015/03/news-img.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="text-left">
                  <h3>CURSOS</h3>
                          <p>sample text</p>
                  <div class="row"> 
                        </div>
      </div>
    </div></li>

  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Any idea for improvements ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why change size if you hide it? Just save the open one and close it when clicking

Comment: The question is unanswerable at the moment because we don't know how your html is laid out and how your toggle_visibility is called, Can you make a Short, Self Contained, Compilable, Example

Comment: Please show rendered html with more than one div. We are not going to fire up a server and put your php there to see how it works. Please cooperate with us to get the best answers

Comment: As soon as possible a jsfiddle is linked